# Rails - How to simply mock current_user (OmniAuth) on Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, testunit

I am trying to figure out how can I mock (simply) current_user inside my unit tests in Rails? (I am using Test::Unit). I tried to look on Google and StackOverflow but nothing really helpful!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in a unit test then you should probably be passing in current_user to your process. When testing from a higher level where you will actually care about current_user, OmniAuth has some mocking for tests.

Look Here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you define roles though? If you were trying to run integration tests on users/admins, the mock_auth hash does not let you change the role conditionally... what am I missing?

Comment: the mocking that is described above is really setting up the auth hash that your application would be receiving from an Oauth provider. Unless the provider passes a role option in their hash, this would have nothing to do with roles.

Comment: Yes, I figured the way to do this was actually create the admin user with the same `uid` that omniauth returns, then log them in. This way the user is found and logged in as admin instead of being created.